# Computing compactly supported dR cohomology for a product space

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

> Compute $H^p_c(\mathbb{R}^k \times S^{n-k})$ for $0 < k < n$ and $0 \le p \le n$ where $H^p_c$ denotes the compactly supported de Rham cohomology.

Let $U = \mathbb{R}^k \times (S^{n-k} \setminus \{a\})$ and $V = \mathbb{R}^k \times (S^{n-k} \setminus \{b\})$. Now these cover our space and $U \cap V= \mathbb{R}^k \times (S^{n-k} \setminus \{a,b\})$ and $U \cup V = \mathbb{R}^k \times S^{n-k}$.

However we can see that $U = \mathbb{R}^k \times (S^{n-k} \setminus \{a\}) \simeq \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^{n-k} \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$ and similarly for $V \simeq \mathbb{R}^n$.

Since $\mathbb{R}^k \times S^{n-k}$ has dimension $n$ we know that $H_c^{n}(\mathbb{R}^k \times S^{n-k}) = \mathbb{R}$.

Now the compactly supported Mayer-Vietoris gives $$\dots \longrightarrow H^p_{c}(U \cap V) \longrightarrow H^p_c(\mathbb{R}^n) \oplus H^p_{c}(\mathbb{R}^n) \longrightarrow H^p_{c}(U \cup V) \longrightarrow \dots$$

but $H^p_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is zero for any $p$ other than $n$  so I'm left with short exact sequences $$0 \longrightarrow H^p_{c}(U \cup V) \longrightarrow H^{p+1}_{c}(U \cap V) \to 0.$$

Now I'm stuck with computing $H^{p+1}_{c}(U \cap V)$. How can I figure out what the cohomology is for this intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $U\cap V=\mathbb{R}^k\times (S^{n-k}\setminus\{a,b\})$, and $S^{n-k}\setminus\{a,b\}\cong \mathbb{R}^{n-k}\setminus\{0\}\cong S^{n-k-1}\times\mathbb{R}$. Hence, we find
$$U\cap V\cong \mathbb{R}^{k+1}\times S^{n-k-1}$$
Now, Poincaré duality for compactly supported cohomology tells us that $H^p_c(U\cap V)\cong H_{n-p}(U\cap V)=H_{n-p}(\mathbb{R}^{k+1}\times S^{n-k-1})\cong H_{n-p}(S^{n-k-1})$, where we used that the product deformation retracts onto $S^{n-k-1}$. Since you know the (co)homology of the sphere, you can make the relevant substitutions to obtain the compactly supported cohomology of $U\cap V$.

Comment: Can we use the duality theorem here? @quaere-verum

Comment: Do you mean Poincaré duality? If you can use Poincaré duality for compactly supported cohomology, then you do not have to use induction. But I don't know if your source has already covered Poincaré duality. In which case, you would use induction. @Levander

Comment: I'm looking for a proof using the Poincaré duality as I have covered material on that, but I couldn't find one that would have been applicable here. @quaere-verum

Comment: Okay. Well then you should be able to conclude from what I wrote, as you can compute the compactly supported cohomology of $S^{n-k-1}\times\mathbb{R}$ using Poincaré duality.

Comment: I think that $S^{n-k-1}\times\mathbb{R} \cong S^{n-k-1}$ so $U\cap V = \Bbb R^k \times S^{n-k-1}$, but we are still left with this product and can't really compute the cohomology for it. For $H^p(S^{n-k-1})$ we have that $H^p(S^{n-k-1}) \cong H^{n-k-1-p}(S^{n-k-1})^*$ since $S^{n-k-1}$ is compact. @quaere-verum

Comment: No, it is absolutely not true that $S^{n-k-1}\times\mathbb{R}\cong S^{n-k-1}$. They are homotopy equivalent, yes, but homotopy equivalence does not induce an isomorphism on compactly supported cohomology. It is quite well-known that $H^p(S^q)=\mathbb{R}$ if $p=0,q$ and $0$ if $0\neq p\neq q$. I figured that you would know this, if you're allowed to use Poincaré duality.

Comment: That I do know, but I don't know how this gives the result on the cohomology for the product $S^{n-k-1}\times\mathbb{R}$? @quaere-verum

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: I see you are using a bit different version of the duality. I'm using that $H^p(M) \cong H^{n-p}_c(M)^*$ for an $n$-manifold. I guess this should still work. @quaere-verum

Comment: It's basically the same statement, you can deduce one from the other. Use whichever one you're comfortable with.

Comment: The setting feels a little off for the case $H^p(M) \cong H^{n-p}_c(M)^*$ as we are starting from the compactly supported cohomology instead of $H^p(M)$. I think I read on Bott & Tu that there was a warning about this in generality? @quaere-verum

Comment: No, the statement I made is true for any oriented manifold. If there are further uncertainties about what you should be doing, I would recommend consulting the relevant literature. What I told you above should be more than what is needed for you to be able to finish the computation.